# What is the proper way for fabric to run two separate commands on two separate servers?

Tags: python, fabric

Say I have two commands with associated parameters:

- `command1`
- `command2`

I want to run the first command on **ServerA** and the second on **ServerB**

Is the right way to do that in fabric by changing the `env`?

give or take, is the below the correct way of doing so? Can't I have the list of hosts include all the servers and I get to choose to tell the `run` method on which server to execute?

```
env.hosts = ['ServerA']
run( command1 )
env.hosts = ['ServerB']
run( command2 )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given fabric limitations, apparently the best way to do this is by using the `execute` method rather than the `run`.

```
from fabric.tasks import execute

def execute_task(command,
                 host):                  
    """
        wrapper around the execute task of fabric. 
        It runs the command remotely via ssh. 
    """    
    return execute(command, host=host)
```

It will work well if the ssh password is the same since you can set the `env.password` in the environment and you will not be asked for password.